# How to get textarea text with line breaks?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, text

How to get text of textarea including linebreaks. I need it because I want to send the text by XMLHttpRequest to ASP.NET HttpHandler(.ashx) and keep the initial form of that text.
My code:

```
function BUTTON_CLICK() {
    XMLHttpRequest ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var text = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
           document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajax.open("POST", "Code/myHttpHandler.ashx?text=" + text, true);

    ajax.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Linebreaks should be there as : `\r\n` 
If you log it in a browser, it should not be display as well, but if you look at the source of your log, they should be displayed. (Ctrl+U on Firefox for example)

Comment: @PoulsQ I've sent the text to HttpHandler after doing some processes it returned that text but there were no linebreaks. That processes don't affect the linebreaks of white spaces.

Comment: Ok, did you try to replace `\n` by other caracters ? Like this for example : `yourHTMLString.Replace("\n", "|-|");` and when you receive your text, you just make a split on `|-|`

Comment: maby not ideal but you can replace linebreaks in text with something, after that when you get request in your controller replace something to <br> or vbclf

Answer (score 2):

Please try it

```
var text = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;    
var myLineBreak = text.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />");
```